# I am getting undefined symbol error while trying to import tensorflow_text in google colab

Tags: tensorflow

I have downloaded all dependencies but still unable to import `import tensorflow_text` for bert

installed all libraries and dependencies but still getting

> NotFoundError:
> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_text/python/metrics/_text_similarity_metric_ops.so:
> undefined symbol:
> _ZNK10tensorflow8OpKernel11TraceStringERKNS_15OpKernelContextEb

Comment: Hi @zuciso, I was able to import tensorflow_text in colab without erros, kindly check the [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/bf49942f95eb502d70820b2a96bfbed0/untitled247.ipynb#scrollTo=iyfd9yxct8j6). Please share some sample code that you are trying to execute so that we can assist you better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @user11530462 helps in collab but on top of it, if you are running on docker, the error you have mentioned,

> NotFoundError: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_text/python/metrics/_text_similarity_metric_ops.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK10tensorflow8OpKernel11TraceStringERKNS_15OpKernelContextEb

generally shows when TF is has a separate [ABI](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) than the TensorFlow that TF.Text was built against. If in this docker image you reinstall TensorFlow using pip (pip install -U tensorflow==2.3.0) you will get rid of the error.

Both tf and tf_text should be installed with pip.